# Getting an error when trying to start the "ntpdate.service" for RHEL7.1

Tags: ntp, rhel7, ntpdate

I am trying to restart services for openstack, and under my `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` I run a `systemctl start ntpdate.service` and get the following error:

```
    May 31 12:05:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Set time via NTP...
    May 31 12:06:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: ntpdate.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    May 31 12:06:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Set time via NTP.
    May 31 12:06:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit ntpdate.service entered failed state.
    May 31 12:06:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: ntpdate.service failed.
```

I also can't seem to find the `ntp.log` in the `/var/log/` directory. I believe this is also screwing up my `rabbitmq-server.service`, but one problem at the time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that `ntpd` was installed as well as the `ntpdate.service`, so they were conflicting with the port that they were using. I need to use `ntpdate.service`, so I just rand the command `systemctl stop ntpd` and then restarted `ntpdate` with `systemctl start ntpd`. I then checked the status with `systemctl status ntpdate.service` and it was `active`.